# .data( ) jquery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to get the number of data stored on an element an then iterate through them ?

For example i would like to do something like :

```
for(;elmt.data().length<i++;){
   //iterate thro elmt.data
}
```

Comment: btw elmt.data().length won't work

Comment: please don't forget to upvote and accept answers that were helpful for you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.data()` returns an object that has no attribute `length`,
but this will work:

```
$.each($('#someElement').data(), function (key, value) {
    console.log(key,value);
});
```

Comment: console will be undefined in IE - this will work perfectly in proper browsers though :)